# Retrieving all validator accounts with the Go Substrate RPC Client

Tags: staking, validator, golang, go-substrate-rpc-client

My goal is to get a list of the stash account addresses of all validators using the golang substrate client.

**Context**
My approach so far is to take inspiration from the polkadotjs application and other apps that use it. With the polkadotjs client fetching all stash accounts can be achieved with the derive api by calling `api.derive.staking.stashes()`. Under the hood this calls `api.query.staking.validators.keys()`, from what I gather this retrieves all the keys with the prefix "Staking" and function "Validators". With the golang client, I am able to get a list of StorageKeys that are under "Staking" - "Validators", however, I can not make sense of them in the same way the polkadotjs client can, which seems to automatically decode the arguments from a storage key.

**Question** How do I decode/retrieve the argument from a types.StorageKey to an account ID in the golang substrate client? Or, alternatively, how do I query all stash addresses with the golang client?

**EDIT: Answer**

Resolved the issue:

````
// get stash accounts
func (sh *SubstrateHarvester) getStashAccounts() ([]string, error) {
    var stashStorageKeys []string

    // Create a key for Staking_Validators (gsrpc does not allow w/o argument, hence override func)
    key, err := sh.CreateStorageKeyUnsafe("Staking", "Validators")
    if err != nil {
        return stashStorageKeys, err
    }

    // This func takes ~4-5 seconds to execute
    stashKeys, err := sh.GetKeysLatest(key)
    if err != nil {
        return stashStorageKeys, err
    }

    for _, key := range stashKeys {
        validatorAddress, err := sh.decodeStashKey(key)
        if err != nil {
            continue // FIXME improve error handling
        }

        stashStorageKeys = append(stashStorageKeys, validatorAddress)
    }

    return stashStorageKeys, nil
}```
````

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "Golang Substrate client"? Substrate is the blockchain development framework that is used to build the reference implementations of Polkadot/Kusama and all of the parachains that I know of; Substrate is a Rust framework. There is a Golang implementation of the Polkadot Host called Gossamer that is in development. It seems like your question really relates to decoding something (possibly something that was SCALE-encoded), which shouldn't be dependent on the client you're using. Are you able to rephrase your question?

Comment: It was pointed out to me that you're probably talking about this, which makes complete sense https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client

Comment: @DanForbes thanks - that's indeed the client I meant. In the meantime we've solved it so I'll post the answer below.

Comment: Could you please share the code how you generate the keys? Otherwise you can ask in the GSRPC repo how to query a map.

Comment: This is the related code that includes the query for all validators with a custom created storage key: https://github.com/momentum-xyz/harvester/blob/cf5f67ce6fff9928f3d2b911235ae793628e8bf0/pkg/substrate/validators.go#L278

Comment: @jvdp would you be so kind as to writing up the answer below  . This could be useful for other members of this community too.